# how to hide component is react and show another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

could you please tell me how to hide the component in reactJS and show another component?I have one button and text (`hello`).on button click, I want to hide button as well as text and show another text `bye`
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/50lj63xvk

```
showBankDetail = () => {
    console.log("====");
    this.setState({
      validForm: true
    });
  };
  render() {
    const validForm = !this.state.validForm;
    return { validForm } ? (
      <div>
        heloo<button onClick={this.showBankDetail}>hide</button>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div>bye</div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to put it on a separate variable first

```
showBankDetail = () => {
  console.log("====");
  this.setState({
    validForm: true
  });
};

render() {
  const validForm = !this.state.validForm;
  let form;
  if (validForm) {
    form = (<div>
            heloo<button onClick={this.showBankDetail}>hide</button>
          </div>);
  } else {
    form = (<div>bye</div>);
  }
  return ({form});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`{ validForm }` is creating an object with property `validForm` and value of validForm (e.g. true or false). You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Your code should look like this

```
showBankDetail = () => {
  console.log("====");
  this.setState({
    validForm: true
  });
};
render() {
  const validForm = !this.state.validForm;
  return validForm ? (
    <div>
      heloo<button onClick={this.showBankDetail}>hide</button>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div>bye</div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you should look at. First off you want to toggle the validForm state, so do that in the showBankDetail function. You could return different elements based on validForm, but you can also do it inline. See:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      validForm: false
    };
  }
  showBankDetail = () => {
    this.setState({
      validForm: !this.state.validForm
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.validForm ?
          <div>heloo</div> :
          <div>bye</div>
        }
        <button onClick={this.showBankDetail}>hide</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```